# merge a list into a nested lists of equal content

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

There is a list:

```
[1,1,1,2,2,1,1]
```

that needs to be converted to into nested lists with equal content:

```
[[1,1,1], [2,2], [1,1]]
```

I'm looking for a functional way to achieve this and was thinking of Ramda's mapAccum, but I can't get my head around it. Any ideas?

Comment: `groupWith(equals)` should do it.  It accepts a binary predicate and groups the elements together so long as it returns `true`

Comment: Very elegant solution!

Comment: @ScottSauyet Post as answer so OP can mark as solved?

Comment: @izhaki: OK.  It's posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ramda's [`groupWith`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#groupWith) accepts a binary predicate and groups successive elements together so long as the predicate is true:

```js
console.log(R.groupWith(R.equals)([1,1,1,2,2,1,1]))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```